# Quiero reproducir musica en mi celular desde la trajeta sd usando el onItemClick de android studio

Tags: android

esto es lo que tengo dentro del :

```
 listamusica.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long pos) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                Toast to = Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,  "Has pulsado la posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                to.show();


                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,pos);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Hola Robinson, podrias aclarar cual es el problema.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio revisa [ask], recuerda aportar detalles que ayuden a solucionar el problema, ¿Cual es el problema y que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Hola Buen Dia, si lo que sucede es que estoy realizando un reproductor de musica en android studio, lo presento en un ListView que se carga con un Cursor .Soy -Robinson.. Agradezco Su Ayuda .Soy un estudiante de Desarrollo.